# Creating two EC2 Instances with the same public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to emulate an environment where two computers are connected to the same network using EC2 instances.

I tried creating a VPC with a public and private subnets. I connected a NAT gateway to the private subnet and then created an instance in private subnet and it doesn't seem to have public ip. Is there another way to approach to create this environment

Comment: The NAT Gateway should be connected to the Public Subnet. The private subnets should have a Route Table entry that points to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: What is your actual goal? You mention "creating two EC2 instances with the same public IP" -- can you tell us what you are wanting to achieve with this? Do you want _outbound_ traffic to 'appear' to come from the same IP address? Or are you wanting to route _incoming_ traffic to two different instances simultaneously? More information, please.

Comment: I want to emulate two devices connected to the same network.

Comment: When you say "two devices connected to the same network", are you wanting them to communicate _with each other_, or with something outside of the network? If two Amazon EC2 instances are in the same VPC, they can communicate with each other via their Private IP address. There is no need to 'emulate' it, because that's how it actually _is_ configured.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you are saying. I think my initial understanding of VPC and subnets were off. Thank you for the help @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

> private subnet and it doesn't seem to have public ip.

That's correct. Instances in private subnets do not have public IP. However, they do access the internet through NAT which as a single public IP. This means that for any external API/service, the two instance will seem to have same IP address.

Comment: Ok that makes sense and is that the same logic for why we need a bastion host to access private instances? Also if I had two instances in the same subnet would that mean they are on the same network?

Comment: @rockym VPC creates a network. 2 instances in a subnet, means that they are in, well..., same subnet, which is part of VPC network.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. I think my understanding of VPC was a off when I first tried to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Load Balancer as the public interface and a auto scaling to scale to 2 instances of ec2